# MongoDB "Cannot read property 'constructor' of null"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
  const stats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { tour: tourId },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$tour',
        nRating: { $sum: 1 },
        avgRating: { $avg: '$rating' },
},
    },
  ]);
  console.log(stats);

  await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(tourId, {
    ratingsQuantity: stats[0].nRating,
    ratingsAverage: stats[0].avgRating,
  });
};

reviewSchema.post('save', function () {
  this.constructor.calcAverageRatings(this.tour);
});

reviewSchema.pre(/^findOneAnd/, async function (next) {
  this.r = await this.findOne();
  // console.log(this.r);
  next();
});

reviewSchema.post(/^findOneAnd/, async function () {
  // await this.findOne(); does NOT work here, query has already executed
  await this.r.constructor.calcAverageRatings(this.r.tour);
});
```

this.r has value of null. So the query that assigned to this.r returns null, but constructor is predefined for reviewSchema's query middlewares.

Comment: What's supposed to be `this` ? You might want to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the context `this` to your callback functions, or maybe it's `reviewSchema` that should be binded.

Comment: I did no change on code and it is working properly now.

Comment: I found that I just kept making update request with a tour's id instead of review id.

Answer (score 0):

reviewSchema.statics.calcAverageRating
missing 's' in static

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).